# Globalization in MYSQL using .Net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, web-services, globalization

i have used the mysql database which we used for the webservice for mobile applications.

In the mobile application have 2 logins as per the languages like arabic and english.

So while user want login as arabic that full session was need to set as arabic session using nls setting.its same for the english

they want see the arabic and english records vice versa according to that login.

so i tired to change the session which we passing from the mobile login.but i cant able to session alter in mysql data base.

In oracle have the solutions but my sql have not solutions which match the my requirement.

please suggest and help me to do this ..

Thnaks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very clear. Are you saying you are unable to alter a session variable from a dotnet web endpoint on your server, based on a language selection data item from your client? How do you know -- what are the visible symptoms of failure? What have you tried? Are you employing the standard dotnet session management scheme, or something else?

Comment: hi ollie jones thanks for your comment..i am speaking about not dotnet session. i ask about my sql server query side